# Codeigniter active record does not retrive any results while the identical normal query works fine

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a codeigniter active record query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('noor_content');
$this->db->where("language",$lang);
foreach ($provs as $prov){
   $this->db->or_like("keywords",$prov);
}
$this->db->limit("14");
$this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
$data = $this->db->get();
```

This displays the following error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 14' at line 4

SELECT * FROM (`noor_content`) WHERE `language` = 3 AND IS NULL ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 14
```

But when I run the `$this->db->last_query();` and paste it in the phpmyadmin, it just reads the correct results out of the database.

```
echo $this->db->last_query();exit();
Which results:

SELECT * FROM (`noor_content`) WHERE `language` = 3 AND `keywords` LIKE '%تخار%' OR `keywords` LIKE '%بغلان%' ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

I really am stuck with this. Any help and suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: i think its problem with the word is not readable format for the mysql

Comment: Then why don't you go with the normal querying structure!?

Comment: Is `$lang` an array? What is stored in the `$lang` variable?

Comment: `AND IS NULL` column is missing