# can not fetch records by using codeigniter 4 Model

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

i am creating restful api, i have created my model in codeignter 4 and in controller when i try to fetch record it gives me this error

---

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL
ORDER BY `id` DESC' at line 3;
```

---

am fetching like in controller

```
    $model = new PlacesModel();
    $data['places'] = $model->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll();
    return $this->respond($data);
```

---

i did not mentioned any null or limit then why am getting this ?

Comment: It seems that it is somewhat related to the CodeIgniter Model, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/24694120/367456 (no answer thought).

Comment: @hakre everything looks good and normal brother, no error in words or anything

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72676656/edit) and show us your `PlacesModel` class, please.